# Record System.err flow in a file when running jar in python scripts

Tags: java, python, stderr

I have a jar file running on commandline using python scripts. The jar file may throw exceptions or crashes sometime. I want to record those occurrence and exceptions in a file. I'm using `sys.stderr` and `sys.stdout`, both seem unable to catch the exceptions. I'm writing to ask how can I do that in python script.

Answer (score 0):

A simple run with a pipe yields:

```
def run_capture(command):
    import subprocess
    child = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    (output, errput) = child.communicate()
    print "Out:'%s'" % output
    print "Err:'%s'" % errput
```

All output is captured.

If i change the `stderr = subprocess.PIPE` to `stderr = file("destfile.txt", "w")` the stderr output goes to the requested file.